# Javascript form validation dom selector

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm having trouble linking the text input field named "color" to a conditional statement. Here is my vanilla JS code.

```
function validateForm(form) {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["color"].value;
if (x === "red") {

    alert("Guess again!");
    return false;
}

}
```

here is the html form.

```
        <form name: "myForm" action="http://www.severien.com/grit/formecho.php" target="_blank" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Personal Info:</legend>
            First Name:
            <br><input class="input" type="text" name="firstname" required min="2" maxlength="20"><br> Last Name:
            <br><input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" required min="2" maxlength="20"><br> Color:
            <br><input class="input" type="text" name="color" maxlength="20"> <br><b>
                Money</b> in my pocket:<br> <input type="number" name="money" required max="1000000"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: If one of the answers below solved your issue, please remember to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` attribute of your `form` was mistyped, it has to be `name="myForm"`, not `name: "myForm"`.

```js
function validateForm(form) {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["color"].value;
  if (x === "red") {

    alert("Guess again!");
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="http://www.severien.com/grit/formecho.php" target="_blank" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Info:</legend>
    First Name:
    <br><input class="input" type="text" name="firstname" required min="2" maxlength="20"><br> Last Name:
    <br><input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" required min="2" maxlength="20"><br> Color:
    <br><input class="input" type="text" name="color" maxlength="20"> <br><b>
                Money</b> in my pocket:<br> <input type="number" name="money" required max="1000000"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```